# Spectrum analyzer as source of electromagnetic interference

Tags: emc, spectrum-analyzer

I was wondering if someone could enlighten me on this. I would like to know whether spectrum analyzers can be inherently the source of interference to other components or not?

Following is the block diagram of spectrum analyzer which is copied from (Frenzel, L. (1995). Communication electronics. New York, N.Y.: Glencoe.)

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about an all-analog, CRT-based spectrum analyzer, or a digitizing spectrum analyzer using a LCD for the display?

Comment: Well the diagram above is from an old book and obviously technology back then was not in LCD era yet. My question was more about other components in the block diagram above. Although your comment is valid and CRT display is definitely in the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly could be.  There is nothing special about spectrum analyzers.  Any piece of electronic equipment could potentially be a source of interference.

Edit: let's work through your block diagram.

- Input attenuator.  Passive component.  Shielded for dynamic range.  This will not produce any EMI.
- Input amplifier.  Active component.  Shielded for dynamic range.  This should not produce any interference unless it is perhaps badly misbehaving.
- Mixer.  Could be active or passive.  Shielded for dynamic range and LO leakage.  Could let out some of the LO frequency if not shielded correctly.
- Sweep generator.  Active component.  May or may not be shielded.  Could possibly produce low frequency EMI, especially if it is driving the coil of a YTO.
- Local oscillator.  Active component.  Shielded to prevent LO leakage.  Should not produce EMI if shielded correctly.
- Filter.  Passive component.  Shielded for dynamic range.  Should not produce EMI.
- Detector.  Passive nonlinear component.  Shielded for dynamic range.  Should not produce EMI.
- Video amp.  Active component.  Shielded for dynamic range.  Could possibly produce low frequency EMI.

Your diagram is missing some very important components, though.  Namely, power supplies and control circuitry.  These components are less likely to be as shielded as the RF signal chain and therefore are likely to produce far more EMI.

Here's something interesting to note, though:  user123753 mentions using a spectrum analyzer to measure it's own EMI.  If you try that on a spectrum analyzer that has a leaky LO, you will not be able to see it on the analyzer!

Comment: Thanks Alex. I was in the process of editing the first post and add the block diagram that you answered. Your comment is a fair comment but what component in above diagram can be more likely the cause of such interference?

Comment: Most likely none of the above.  Power supply, control computer, display, etc. are far more likely to be sources of interference.  The RF stuff has to be well shielded to prevent external interference and so is likely to be far less a source of interference as some of the other components.

Answer (score 1):

Spectrum Analyzers can definitely cause EMI.  In fact, if the EMI is high enough and within the SPA's frequency range, connecting an antenna to the SPA's input will allow you to see the EMI on the SPA's display.  A low noise preamp between the antenna and the SPA input can further aid in letting the SPA examine its own emissions.  I've personally done this numerous times.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When you say "EMI is high enough" you mean the EMI caused by SPA itself,  is high enough. Right? and if so, my main question was what actually generates that level of EMI in SPA?

Answer (score 0):

Note that in a recent design, a spectrum analyzer is a lot more likely to look like: attenuator/amplifier, ADC, microprocessor doing an FFT, and an LCD for output. Depending on the signal levels you care about, the attenuator/amplifier section may well be built into the ADC chip.

That doesn't eliminate EMI sources (by any stretch of the imagination) but it does mean that a lot of what you're dealing with is entirely *different* sources. Digital signals are doing their best to be square waves, so they usually have quite a bit of energy well above the rated clock speed of the bus (or whatever) involved.